# Changing the ColorIndex of a DataLabel is not behaving as stated by the documentation

Tags: vba, colors, powerpoint

I am trying to change the color of a DataLabel, however so far I was only able to change the color to red or black.

I've tried to set the ColorIndex to the "Values" as well as "Names" according to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex

```
dim objChart as PowerPoint.Chart

objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.ColorIndex = 0
```

This code will change my DataLabel to Black, so far so good. Hoewever:

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.ColorIndex = 8
```

will change the color to red, just as most of the other numbers (I have not tried all of them). Even better:

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.ColorIndex = wdWhite
```

will throw an Error that `wdWhite` is not defined, while it is executed in debugging mode. If printing in the immediate window `? wdWhite` it is Empty, which explains the Error as I use `Option Explicit`. However I am quite confused that it is not defined.

Also if I let

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.ColorIndex = 0
```

and then print it in the immediate window it will return -1.
So I am kind of confused what is going on. So far I have not worked with `ColorIndex` but only with `Color.RGB` so I am not sure if or what I am doing wrong.

Do I maybe have to include a specifiy library? 
Also maybe as additional information I am coding a macro in Excel that populates charts in a PowerPoint.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `wdWhite` will only work if you include a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library. I think you're looking in the wrong place as far as documentation goes. Also, all your `DataLabels` are spelled wrong.

Comment: Ah okay, I will check that out. As for the spelling mistake I just retyped the code so that is where that comes from. But I edited my question, thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: Do you copy charts from Excel into PowerPoint, or create the charts directly in PowerPoint?

Comment: Neither, I have an existing Chart in a PowerPoint which I modify (I change some values and according to the values other properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I think you want [`Font.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.font.color) instead of `ColorIndex`.

2) You can use the named [color constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/color-constants), e.g. `vbRed`, `vbBlack`, etc.

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.Color = vbWhite
```

Or you can use [`RGB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function) for other colors as needed:

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.Color = RGB(100, 50, 0)
```

Comment: Fun Fact I only tried `objChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(2).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)` before which did not work, but without the `.RGB` it works.... ugh.. any idea why here `.Color` does not have the method `.RGB`?

Comment: No problem, glad to help out. I think `Color` takes a `Long` value, which is what `RGB` returns. If you put `? vbRed` or `? vbBlack` in the Immediate Window, you'll see the return result is equal to their RGB value - 255 and 0 respectively.